# asp core: where the "Shared" folder is configured and how to change its path?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

This line in cshtml

```
<partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
```

suppose to search for _CookieConsentPartial.cshtml in `\Pages\Shared` folder.

Could I configure web app "to search for _CookieConsentPartial" in  `\Pages` folder?

I have deleted Shared folder and moved  _CookieConsentPartial.cshtml to \Pages folder but after this `<partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />` stop working - `<partial name="\_CookieConsentPartial.cshtml" />` works - but this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I fail to reproduce your issue by moving `_CookieConsentPartial.cshtml` file to `Pages` folder. What is your project type and version?

Answer (score 1):

For configuring additional search folder path, you could configure `RazorViewEngineOptions` like:

```
       services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => {
            options.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Shared-1/{0}.cshtml");
        });
```

By default, PageViewLocationFormats already defined `/Pages/{0}.cshtml`

```
     // Remarks:
    //     Locations are format strings (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)
    //     which may contain the following format items:
    //     {0} - View Name {1} - Page Name
    //     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions.PageViewLocationFormats
    //     work in tandem with a view location expander to perform hierarchical path lookups.
    //     For instance, given a Page like /Account/Manage/Index using /Pages as the root,
    //     the view engine will search for views in the following locations: /Pages/Account/Manage/{0}.cshtml
    //     /Pages/Account/{0}.cshtml /Pages/{0}.cshtml /Pages/Shared/{0}.cshtml /Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml
    public IList<string> PageViewLocationFormats { get; }
```